# How to convert on python side this eight bytes to number ( unsigned long)?

Tags: python-2.7

I converted unsigned long from c++ to eight bytes and send over network(0 position is the least significant).
How to convert on python side this eight bytes to number ( unsigned long)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html):

```
import struct

struct.unpack('Q', data)
```

Do carefully study the module documentation; the format `'Q'` means 'unsigned long long', which has a standard size of 8 bytes. You can add a flag to indicate byte-order and alignment behaviour. Without a flag native byte order is assumed, use `<` or `>` to signify little or big endian byte ordering for example.

Comment: @Martijin Pieters If I have unsigned long of eight bytes can it be converted to signed of eight bytes ( one bit is missing for sign, positive range is twice smaller) ?